# Shopware 6 Customer Group Extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig, shopware

I am trying to extend the customer group in Shopware 6 for having an extra string, which can be assigned to each customer group in the customer group settings in administration, for later usage.

1. First I created a migration containing a new database entry to the table "customer_group" -> When I "SELECT * FROM customer_group" I can see my extra entry there and the value is NULL.
2. I created an EntityExtension to join the SQL-Entry and the Shopware-Entry and I also created a subscriber, that should ensure the Shopware-Entry is loaded, when product groups are loaded.
3. And finally I created a html.twig, which should overwrite the referenced html.twig to ensure there is a "sw-text-field" in the customer group settings in administration -> That also works fine, the twig gets overwritten.

Now to my problem: When I put in a test string into my custom sw-text-field and click the save button I get no error message, but my test string also doesn't get written to the SQL-Database. I tried to set my custom value in the SQL table to some test string - which works - but I also can't output the string in the Shopware-HTML-Twig to see it in the administration either, so my guess is that I did something wrong linking the database-entry with the shopware-entry. I also tried strictly following the Shopware 6 documentation, but was unable to find a solution. Has anyone done something like this before and is able to help me? Thanks in advance for any answer - Below is my code:

```php
// Shopware Version 6.3.9999999.9999999-dev

//directory: CustomerGroupPlugin\src\Resources\config\services.xml

<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="CustomerGroupPlugin\ModelExtension\CustomerGroupExtension">
            <tag name="shopware.entity.extension"/>
        </service>

        <service id="CustomerGroupPlugin\ModelExtension\Subscriber\MySubscriber">
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
        </service>
        
        <service id="CustomerGroupPlugin\ExtendPage\Storefront\Subscriber\CustomerRegisterSubscriber">
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
            <argument type="service" id="customer.repository"/>
            <argument type="service" id="customer_group.repository"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>


//directory: CustomerGroupPlugin\src\ModelExtension\CustomerGroupExtension.php

<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace CustomerGroupPlugin\ModelExtension;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Aggregate\CustomerGroup\CustomerGroupDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityExtension;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Runtime;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\StringField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;

class CustomerGroupExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            (new StringField('test_string', 'testString'))->addFlags(new Runtime())
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return CustomerGroupDefinition::class;
    }
}


//directory: CustomerGroupPlugin\src\ModelExtension\Subscriber\MySubscriber.php

<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace CustomerGroupPlugin\ModelExtension\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Event\EntityLoadedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Cms\SalesChannel\Struct\TextStruct;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\Aggregate\CustomerGroup\CustomerGroupEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\CustomerEvents;

class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CustomerEvents::CUSTOMER_GROUP_LOADED_EVENT => 'onCustomerGroupsLoaded'
        ];
    }

    public function onCustomerGroupsLoaded(EntityLoadedEvent $event): void
    {
        /** @var CustomerGroupEntity $customerGroupEntity */
        foreach ($event->getEntities() as $customerGroupEntity) {
            $customerGroupEntity->addExtension('testString', new TextStruct());
        }
    }
}


//directory: CustomerGroupPlugin\src\Resources\app\administration\src\module\sw-settings-customer-group\page\sw-settings-customer-group-detail\sw-settings-customer-group-detail.html.twig

{% block sw_settings_customer_group_detail_content_card_name %}
    {% parent %}
    <sw-text-field v-model="customerGroup.testString"
        label="Teststring Here">
    </sw-text-field>
{% endblock %}


//directory: CustomerGroupPlugin\src\Resources\app\administration\src\main.js

import template from './module/sw-settings-customer-group/page/sw-settings-customer-group-detail/sw-settings-customer-group-detail.html.twig';

Shopware.Component.override('sw-settings-customer-group-detail', {
    template
});


//directory: CustomerGroupPlugin\src\Migration\Migration1610627867.php

<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace CustomerGroupPlugin\Migration;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Migration\MigrationStep;

class Migration1610627867 extends MigrationStep
{
    public function getCreationTimestamp(): int
    {
        return 1610627867;
    }

    public function update(Connection $connection): void
    {
        $connection->executeUpdate('
            ALTER TABLE `customer_group`
            ADD `test_string` VARCHAR(255);
        ');
    }

    public function updateDestructive(Connection $connection): void
    {
        // implement update destructive
    }
}

//directory: CustomerGroupPlugin\src\CustomerGroupPlugin.php

<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace CustomerGroupPlugin;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Context\UninstallContext;

class CustomerGroupPlugin extends Plugin
{
    public function uninstall(UninstallContext $context): void
    {
        parent::uninstall($context);

        if ($context->keepUserData()) {
            return;
        }

        $connection = $this->container->get(Connection::class);

        $connection->executeUpdate('ALTER TABLE `customer_group` DROP COLUMN `test_string`');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the best option in your case is to use Custom Fields. Read that article to understand more https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/developer-guide/custom-fields In this case, you need only add a custom field and override the twig template.

Comment: Okay I haven't thought of creating a Custom Field via Code I only saw, that adding a Custom Field via Admin was for some reason not possible. I will try adding my variable this way right away. Thanks for your thoughts @Valerii Pravoslavnyi

Comment: You can do it in both ways, you can add custom field via code and via admin panel. I prefer to create custom fields during the installation/updating of my plugins.

Comment: I would prefer trying it via code because via admin panel I only have the option to assign the field to "Categories, Products, Manufacturers, Customers, Addresses,Sales Channels and Media" for some reason.

Comment: @ValeriiPravoslavnyi did you actually extend the customer_group or is this a wild guess? Tried that and seems not to be supported (only customer, even in Code)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the event is triggered? You can look in the Symfony console and click for example on the 10 last. There will for example be a 302 redirect. Look there inside and search for an echo or dump ().

To the problem with the twig variable probably you need to add your var to the template:

```
$this->renderView(
  'your-twig-path.html.twig', [
             'group' => your var,
              ...,
              ...
         ]
   );
```

If i remember well "renderView() depends on if it is a JsonResponse or StorefrontController.

Hope i could help something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the CustomerEvents are loaded in the backend. What you are trying is to register in the StoreFront the Register Event. Best way to get the desired event:

Submit for example the register form (or open the desired controller). In case you want the register event go in to your symfony debugger (By clicking for exmaple the statusNumber 200 in the left bottom corner  of your storefront/admin). After that click on the upper left "last 10" button. Type in your search bar left under status "302" (Redirect, where the register event is).  Press search. Click right in the list on the desired Token link.  Select in the sidebar the Event tab. There you will have all fired and not fired events. Probably yours is in the not fired tab (Press ctrl+f and search for "onCustomerGroupsLoaded" to know where in which of both tabs it is). You can attach to one of the fired events in the list. Keep in mind that the dump ouput will be in the redirect. Not on account and not on the Register Form.